# How can I delete a Riak bucket in Python?

Tags: python, riak

I want to delete a Riak bucket in order to purge old data from my system. I understand that there is no single Riak API to do this, but instead one [deletes all the keys in the bucket](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/apis/http/#Bucket-Operations), which effectively deletes it. Riak does provide an API to fetch all the keys, so this is fairly straightforward.

I found some [code online](https://github.com/cmurphycode/riak-delete-bucket) to do this, but it was written in JavaScript and runs under Node. I want something in Python. This is probably a simple thing to do. Does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like I said in the question, I figured this was pretty simple, especially with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, so I developed a script to do this. I started with the Riak `keys=true` (i.e. non-chunked) [mode](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/apis/http/HTTP-List-Keys/#Request), but that failed on my larger buckets. I switched to chunked mode (`keys=stream`), but the output was not a single JSON object anymore, but a series of concatenated objects (i.e. `{...}{...}...{...}`. A colleague provided me with a regex to split the JSON objects out from the aggregated Riak response, which I parsed and processed sequentially. Not too bad. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# script to delete all keys in a Riak bucket

import json
import re
import requests
import sys

def processChunk(chunk):
    global key_count
    obj = json.loads(chunk.group(2))
    if 'keys' in obj:
        for key in obj['keys']:
            r = requests.delete(sys.argv[1] + '/' + key)
            print 'delete key', key, 'response', r.status_code
            key_count += 1


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'Usage: {0} <http://riak_host:8098/riak/bucket_name>'.format(sys.argv[0])
    print 'Set riak_host and bucket_name appropriately for your Riak cluster.'
    exit(0)

r = requests.get(sys.argv[1] + '?keys=stream')
content = ''
key_count = 0

for chunk in r.iter_content():
    if chunk:
        content += chunk

re.sub(r'(?=(^|})({.*?})(?={|$))', processChunk, content)

print 'Deleted', key_count, 'keys'
```

While my problem is largely solved at this point, I suspect there are better solutions out there. I welcome people to add them on this page. I won't accept my own answer unless no alternatives are provided after a few weeks.

Comment: We did the same in PHP for Riak-admin console https://github.com/pentium10/riak-admin

Answer (score 2):

If using the python riak-client is an option for you, this can be achieved with less code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import riak

riak_handle = riak.RiakClient(pb_port=8087, protocol='pbc')
riak_bucket = riak_handle.bucket('default')

for keys in riak_bucket.stream_keys():
    for key in keys:
        print('Deleting %s' % key)
        riak_bucket.delete(key)
```

You could adapt that to use arguments if that is your primary use case.

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks for adding it.